# Excel formula for an average where the price increases every day

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average

Can some one help me with a simple forumla in excel for the following problem.

I need to be able to predict an average price for the month. For example, if the current price is $1000 and there are 5 days left until the end of the month, I believe the price will increase £50 p/day. 1050 then 1100 1150 etc So the average price for the last six days will be 1100?

i would like to be able to do a forumla that works it out from the current price, the increase amount and the days left with out having to have a cell for each day etc?

Is this possible? i have tried google but have come up with nothing, a difficult question to articulate.

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/). Sounds like a very simple mathematical formula

Comment: Well I have been using (days left * predicted daily increase amount) + (current price*days left)/ days left so for example in this example (5x50)+(1000*5)/5=1100 which is wrong??

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're having troubles finding the days in the month and the percentage of the month that has already passed / left

To calculate the number of days in the current month use this formula

```
=EOMONTH(NOW(), 0)-EOMONTH(NOW(), -1)
```

To calculate the current day of the month use this formula

```
=DAY(NOW())
```

To calculate the percentage of the month already gone

```
=DAY(NOW()) / (EOMONTH(NOW(), 0)-EOMONTH(NOW(), -1))
```

To calculate the percentage of the month remaining

```
=1 - (DAY(NOW()) / (EOMONTH(NOW(), 0)-EOMONTH(NOW(), -1)))
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer but we need to be able to specify the amount of trading days left in a month, in this case 5. We don't need a formula to calculate the percentage of the month left. thanks again though

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear what you are averaging - is it 5 days or 6?

If you start with 1000 and average 5 days then you are averaging 1000, 1050, 1100, 1150 and 1200 so the average is 1100 - if that's the required result try this formula

`=A2+B2*(C2-1)/2`

where A2 is price, B2 increase amount and C2 days left

If you are averaging 6 days then that starts at 1000 and ends at 1250 so average is 1125 and the formula should be:

`=A2+B2*C2/2`

Comment: This works!! The only thing is, we need to do it so that todays price is not included so there are 5 days left, not including today. We think the price will increase for the next 5 days so 1050, 1100 and so on. How can we adapt your formula for that? thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: So if current is 1000 you just want the average for 1050, 1100, 1150, 1200 and 1250.....which will be 1150 try `=A2+B2*(C2+1)/2`